# Prove that the sequence of partial sum does not admit limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I want to prove that given the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n a_n$$with $a_n\geq 0$ and increasing.
Now then I want to prove that if I consider $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k a_k$, supposing that $S_n$ does not converge (as a conseguence of fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^na_n\neq 0$) then $\nexists \lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$.
My attempt:
$$1)S_{2N+2}-S_{2N}=a_{2N+2}-a_{2N+1}>0 \text{, because} \,a_n\geq 0 \text{ and} \,a_n \text{ increasing}$$
$$2)S_{2N+1}-S_{2N-1}=-a_{2N+1}+a_{2N}<0 \text{, because} \,a_n\geq 0 \text{ and} \,a_n \text{ increasing}$$ From $1)$ the sequence $\{S_{2N}\}_{N\geq 1}$ is increasing, from $2)$ $\{S_{2N-1}\}_{N\geq 1}$ is decreasing with $S_1<0$ and $S_2>0$. So surely the sequence $S_N$ cannot diverge and so the limit does not exist.

Do you think my attempt is correct?

Comment: just to be clear, you are trying to show convergence of $S_n$ right?

Comment: Does the general term converge to $0$?

Comment: The general term does not converge to $0$ so surely the limit of $S_n$ cannot be a real number: $S_n$ could diverge or could not admit a limit. I want to show that under my hyp. the limit does not exist

Comment: @CSquared I want to show that $S_n$ does admit limit!

Answer (score 1):

Given that increasing $a_{n}$, then $a_{n}\rightarrow\sup_{n}a_{n}$, say, $L=\sup_{n}a_{n}$. Since $a_{n}\geq 0$, then $L\geq 0$. Actually $L>0$ if not all $a_{n}=0$.

But then $|(-1)^{n}a_{n}|\rightarrow|L|>0$, the tail of the series does not converge to zero, so the series is not convergent.

**EDIT:**

Let $S_{2N}\rightarrow L$, as $S_{2}>0$ and $\{S_{2N}\}$ is increasing, then $L>0$. Similarly, if $S_{2N+1}\rightarrow M$, then $M<0$. If $\{S_{N}\}$ is convergent, then $L=M$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thansk but this answer does not help me in proving what I want...I want to prove under my hp that the limit of $S_n$ does not exist

Comment: Mate, you can argue by contradiction. If $S_{n}\rightarrow S$, then $S_{n}-S_{n-1}\rightarrow 0$, and you got the tail $(-1)^{n}a_{n}\rightarrow 0$, which I have just disproved.

Comment: Ok what's about my attempt?

Comment: As I noted in my first paragraph, it seems to me that you tried to argue that, if a sequence  that containing increasing and decreasing subsequences, then it does not converge. But I gave you a counterexample of this thought.

Comment: Nope I am arguing that if a series with alternating sign term has $a_n$ that is a sequence that is INCREASING and $a_n>0$ then the limit of $S_n$ does not exist

Comment: The limit that I am considering is not the limit of the genral term but of $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k a_k$

Comment: Now I see what you tried. Okay, maybe you should add extra lines: $S_{2N}\rightarrow L$, since $S_{2N}$ is increasing with $S_{2}>0$, then $L>0$. Similarly, with $S_{2N+1}\rightarrow M$, then $M<0$. But we should have $L=M$, so a contradiction.

Comment: Yes exactly...so the limit does not exist right with my proof right?

Comment: Okay, your proof goes through, nice.