# Series that does not converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, monotone-functions

Let $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n+1}$$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
If $x<-1$, then I can write $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n|x|^n}{n+1}$$ because $x=-|x|$, and then I have that $\frac{|x|^n}{n+1}$ is increasing, but why?
$$\frac{|x|^n}{n+1}<\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n+1}$$ then how can I go further in order to prove that the sequence is increasing?
Once I have done this so the series surely does not converge for $x<-1$, right?

Comment: You ask why exponential grows faster than linear?  Try using calculus.  The names of the variables you used are unfortunate as we normally derive with respect to $x$... but if we were to look at the derivative with respect to $n$ of the top compared to the bottom so we can apply L'Hopitals you should see that the derivative of the numerator grows without bound while the derivative of the denominator is a constant $1$.

Comment: It isn’t increasing for all $n,$ just for $n$ large, like when $1+\frac{1}{n+1}<|x|.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your $a=|x|>1$. At least the term is eventually increasing:

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{a^{n}}{n+1}<\dfrac{a^{n+1 }}{n+2}~~\text{iff}~~\dfrac{n+2}{n+1}<a~~\text{iff}~~1+\dfrac{1}{n+1}<a.
\end{align*}
Since $a>1$, you can always choose $n$ so large such that $1+1/(n+1)<a$, from these $n$ onward, then it is increasing.

Comment: ok thanks so if the sequence is eventually increasing then the series does not converge right? moreover it is right to write the series as I have done in case $x<-1$ (I mean $\sum (-1)^n|x|^n/(n+1)$ ?

Comment: Look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130932/prove-that-the-sequence-of-partial-sum-does-not-admit-limit).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! The expression for the series $$\sum (-1)^n|x|^n/(n+1)$$ is right (for $x<-1$?

Comment: Okay, that is correct as merely a change of variable.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $|x|^n/(n+1)$ is not necessarily increasing, but it is increasing eventually:
$$ \frac{|x|^n}{n+1} < \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n+2} \ \text{if and only if}\ \frac{n+2}{n+1} < |x|$$

But it's simpler to use the Ratio Test.