# Solution verification of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^n+\arctan(n)}$ when $x<-e$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

The series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^n+\arctan(n)}$ is neither divergent or convergent when $x<-e$? as matter of fact $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{e^n+\arctan(n)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{|x|^n}{e^n+\arctan(n)}$ and $\frac{|x|^n}{e^n+\arctan(n)}\sim \frac{|x|^n}{e^n}$ and this last is increasing when $x<-e$.

So referring to this [Prove that the sequence of partial sum does not admit limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4130932/914360) the series cannot diverge or converge since the sequence of partial sum has no limit. I am right?

Comment: A sequence "diverges" precisely when it fails to converge. There are no other possibilities.

Comment: Ok I have read a definition where it is said that the series is indeterminate if the limit of the partial sum does not exist. Anyway is right that this limit does not exist?

Comment: @Sisi If the limit of partial sums doesn't exist, the series diverges. Also, you are using $k$ when it should be $n.$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not correct. You used the limit comparison test, and you didn't compute the partial sum to say it has or not a limit.

In fact if $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing
with $ a_n>0$, then if $$S_N=-a_1+a_2-a_3+...+(-1)^Na_N$$
it is proven, in the reference you gave that
$$S_{2N-1}<S_1<S_2<S_{2N}$$
from here,
$$S_{2N}-S_{2N-1}>S_2-S_1>0$$
So,
$$\lim_{N\to+\infty}(S_{2N}-S_{2N-1})\ge S_2-S_1>0$$
$$\lim_{N\to+\infty}S_N \text{ cannot exist}$$

Let $$a_n=\frac{1}{e^n+\arctan(n)}$$
Applying the root test to the power series $\sum a_nx^n, $ we get
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}|a_n|^{\frac 1n}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{e(1+\frac{\arctan(n)}{e^n})^{\frac 1n}}=$$
$$\frac 1e$$
So, the convergence radius is $ R=e$, and the series $\sum a_nx^n$ diverges if $ x\notin [-R,R]$.

Comment: I have not completely understood...the limit of partial sum exist in case $x<-e$?

Comment: @Sisi we can say that the limit of the partial sum is not finite. i

Comment: In my opinion it does not exist since I have a series of kind $(-1)^na_n$ with $a_n$ increasing as shown in reference...do you think is not right?

Comment: @Sisi How do you prove $ (a_n) $ is inceasing without $~$.

Comment: "Without" what??

Comment: I consider that the general term of my original series is asymptotic to $(-1)|x|^n/e^n$, this last one is something like $(-1)^na_n$ with a_n increasing for $x<-e$ and so from asymptote criterion the series has the same behaviour

Comment: @Sisi You the equivalence $~\frac{|x|^n}{e^n}$ to conclude it is inceasing.

Comment: Yes I use this asymptote equivalence, with the reason expalined in the comment above...what do you think?

Comment: What do you mean by :"the limit of the partial sum does not exist". could it be infinite.

Comment: Does not exists since if $a_n$ is increasing in case of the general term of the series that is $(-1)^na_n$ then I have that the odd term and the even term of the sequence of partial sum form two subsequences that cannot diverge equally. Look here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4130932/914360

Comment: @Sisi Please, have a look at the line i added about the reference you cited.

Comment: Ok so sorry I am a bit confused...this confirms that the limit of $S_n$ does not exist in case $x<-e$? Sorry for the many questions but I am confused

Comment: can you help me in understanding this last thing?